# what are some books/academic journals which I could read on renewable energy/technology?

Tags: chemical-engineering, renewable-energy, environmental-engineering

Book suggestions on renewable energy technologies/sources

Comment: A google search will give you many many sources.

Comment: Here is one: Solar Engineering of Thermal Processes, Duffie & Beckman.

Answer (score 1):

Top 3 in Compendex database are [Energies](https://www.mdpi.com/journal/energies), and this [one](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/renewable-energy) and this [one](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/renewable-and-sustainable-energy-reviews).

Only Energies has full Open Access, the other two supports Open Access but most articles are paid.

ScienceDirect is just a Database used to find an article and read the abstract. For actual access, unless you have an institution credential, you'll have to Google the article and find it elsewhere to download. In all cases, you can use this to search for articles.

Hope this helps.